# Creating a constructor in a test case so that it will only be called once

Tags: java, android, exception, junit, constructor

Trying to create a constructor that is only called once in my unit tests

```
public class ArtistTest extends InstrumentationTestCase{
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "TESTING_SUITE";
    private TestingMusicDAO musicDAO;
    private List<Song> songs;
    private Instrumentation instr;
    MusicService musicService;

    public ArtistTest() throws Exception {
        super();       
        instr = this.getInstrumentation();
        Log.d(TAG_NAME, "Setting up testing songs");
        musicDAO = new TestingMusicDAO(instr.getContext());
        musicService = new MusicServiceImpl(musicDAO);
        musicDAO.getAllSongsFromFile();
        songs = musicDAO.getAllSongs();
        for(Song song : songs)
            Log.d( TAG_NAME, song.toString() );
    }
```

But I get an Exception in constructor error when I run the file as a Android Junit Test. Also here is the stack trace

```
 junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: test0      (java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.intellimec.ilane.ice.mediaservices.ArtistTest.<init>(ArtistTest.java:17)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
 at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:118)
 at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.getTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:148)
 at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:56)
 at   android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:80)
 at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:444)
 at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:425)
 at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:370) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4382)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 )
 at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
 at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
 at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
 at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code you only need to execute one time during test runs into static initializer instead. It should only run once, when the class is loaded (do not reuse this class).

Comment: I would prefer to use a constructor / would like to know the reason for this exception

Comment: Couldn't find a solution in the end, used this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can also write your own setUp() method to initialize your "Music" objects once
See this page for details
http://www.methodsandtools.com/tools/tools.php?junit

Comment: Yes I did but with junit that method will be called for every test, since junit tears down the method a runs it again. Making the testing process very slow as I am generating a music database every time. Hence the constructor

Answer (score 0):

What is at `ArtistTest.java:17`?

If `getInstrumentation` just returns the `private field instr` then it returns null in the call here, resulting in NPE later

Comment: The initialization of the class from super(). Is there a solution?

Comment: How can superclass initialize a field of subclass

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Who is showing which hierarchy of constructors?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a concrete constructor for your test cases.

Better to follow the junit paradigm.

use these annotations to initialize any values that you need initialized once per class.
i.e. @BeforeClass and @AfterClass
Make sure that you define whatever you want o initialize at the class level

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
 //per class attributes initialized here
   instr = this.getInstrumentation();
    Log.d(TAG_NAME, "Setting up testing songs");
    musicDAO = new TestingMusicDAO(instr.getContext());
    musicService = new MusicServiceImpl(musicDAO);
    musicDAO.getAllSongsFromFile();
    songs = musicDAO.getAllSongs();
    for(Song song : songs)
        Log.d( TAG_NAME, song.toString() );
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
 //per class attributes destroyed here
}
```

for any initialization that you need per method, use the following annotations to tell junit to initialize these values per test method

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
 //per method attributes initialized here

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
 //per method attributes destroyed here
}
```

use annotation @Test to designate a method as a test method

i.e.

```
@Test
public void testMethodx() {
}
```